# Want to alert on html from code of .gs file

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications

I have a Google Sheet, wep app - form and want to check the duplicate of input data.

If it's duplication, pop up alert on html page before sending data to Google Sheet.

But, `alert()` from [.gs file of Google Apps Script] seems doesn't work.

I want to alert when [if (position >-1) ] is true.

What am I missing? help me...

```js
function addItem(userInfo) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  var data = ws.getRange(2, 4, ws.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  var codeList = data.map(function(r) {
    return r[0].toString();
  });
  var position = codeList.indexOf(userInfo.studentname); //the code that user input is a number

  if (position > -1) {
    var m1 = userInfo.studentname;

    sendTelegram('"' + m1 + 'no' + '"');

    return true;
  } else {
    ws.appendRow([
      userInfo.bzpatteacher,
      userInfo.bzperiod,
      userInfo.seatnum,
      userInfo.studentname,
      userInfo.reginm,
      new Date(),
    ]);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. The code doesn't include an `alert()` function by the other hand it's not clear what do you mean by "Google Sheet, wep app - form". Please add a [mcve] .

Comment: I would consider checking for duplicates in `addItem()` and if they are found return message to `withSuccessHandler()` message could tell user weather it was a duplicate or not.

Comment: Hi ! Could you please also share a sample of your HTML file *with no sensitive data* ? A way you could get an alert is to use a ```script``` tag in your HTML file which listens from a trigger in your ```.gs``` file. When the condition matches in your Apps Script file then the script in your HTML will detect the condition met and can trigger an [alert()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) from your HTML file. Thanks ! :D

Answer (score -1):

```
codeList.indexOf(userInfo.studentname); //the code that user input is a number
```

If `userInfo.studentname` is of `Number` type, then strict checking by `indexOf` will fail as `codeList` is a array of `String` types.

Try

```
var position = codeList.indexOf(userInfo.studentname.toString());
```